# google map - runtimeexception - error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I just try to view a map on the display, but it does not work. I get an runtimeexception:

```
01-17 19:16:47.066: E/AndroidRuntime(6605): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.maptest/com.example.maptest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
```

Java:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;




public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
 getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

    GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) 
 getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
}


}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.maptest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
  <permission
      android:name="com.example.maptest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>


    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="removed"/>


    <activity
        android:name="com.example.maptest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.EMBED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
           <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

  <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/map"
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The key is v2 and i followed strict the google tutorial i found. I also imported android play services.

Could someone help me please? :)

Comment: in your oncreate Method setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); called two times

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar error when trying the Map API v2. However, I don't know whether it will help you.

My problem was that the google-play-services_lib had to be included as a library. In Eclipse, you can do this as follows:

1. Use the Android SDK Manager to download the library.
2. Create a new "Android Project from existing code" where you point to google-play-services_lib in the folder you used to install the SDK.
3. Under "Project -> Properties -> Android" flag this project as "Is library".
4. In your project, also open "Project -> Properties -> Android" and click on "Add" in the library section. Select the google-play-services_lib.

At least that worked for me.

Comment: mhm, I understand what u mean. But i have a problem: when i try to crate an project from an existing code and navigate to that projeckt, the project is showed, but in grey letters, so i cannot check it...do u know why that could be?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you provide a picture? However, I'm not an Eclipse expert and struggled with this issue for some hours...

Comment: Sorry I cannot insert a picture, because i am a new user here. When I try to import the libary project into my workspace it tells me, that it is allready there, but I think it isnt

Comment: he means this:

http://img843.imageshack.us/img843/6970/stackoverflowquestion.png

can you help?