# Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence', referenced from method gls.a

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

Before I begin I have tried every solution offered under similar questions posted on stackoverflow as well as other forums to no avail:

I have the following code to render maps...It worked for a few days then outright stopped working. I have changed the API keys but also nothing.

```
public class The_Map_Fragment extends SherlockFragment  {
..........
..........
if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); 
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(-1.281509, 36.816974)).zoom(13).build();
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition)); 
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Sorry! unable to Instatntiate Google Maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }


    }
```

My xml is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

My Manifest has all refrences  and permissions ok

```
<permission android:name="com.the.app.rr.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"  
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.the.app.rr.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Required to show current location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
```

When I run I get the error Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence', referenced from method gls.a

Comment: are you using proguard or did you enable it in your project?

Comment: No am not using proguard

Comment: @Jaymo Me too facing same issue did you got any solution??

Comment: it is a device generic issue..I tries in my Nexus 7 and the error persisted whereas while it tries in Moto E everything was working smoothly

Comment: So is there a work around to it...am testing on a Galaxy Nexus

Comment: @goonerdroid I doubt its a Device issue...tested it with 4 other devices and the results are similar, It works some time, other time it doesnt

Comment: How was the problem solved?

Comment: Still hasn't been solved...although there are interesting findings on the reason why the error is being showed

Comment: maybe the following link would help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423267/android-google-map-api-version-2/25693129#25693129

Comment: @E_X Let me setup a VM with a 32bit environment and see if it works on my end

Comment: @Jaymo in addition to that I ended up using a mapView, as the best answer in this link shows (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919048/android-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-8-error-inflatin), the MapView seems to fit better inside the fragment life-cycle.

Comment: Let me look at the answer. I really hope It will solve the issue for me

Comment: Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: @E_X I got a 32 bit machine and did a fresh setup..Imported the code and tried the first solution you offered. That didn't work. So I tried the second solution of using a Mapview still similar results. My test device was a Google Nexus Haven't tired any other phone with the two solutions offered

Comment: @Jaymo ok when you initialize your map, are you requesting the user's current location to be shown in the map? or your just adding the map in xml?!

Comment: @E_X Just showing the map..I have commented out all location based calls.

Comment: @Jaymo I asked you that question; because the error continued to appear due to requesting to get the LatLang for the user without checking if the Location service, network provider is enabled on the user's phone or not.

Comment: now here is the xml mapView that I used: <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/mapview" /> , and within the OncreateView method inside MyFragment class: View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.the_fragment_layout, container, false); MapView mapView = (MapView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.map);
mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     also you need to call the mapViews onResume(), onDestory(), onLowMemory() within each method of the fragments life cycle :)

Comment: I opted to use MapView Instead and as pointed it eventually worked. The problem it appears was emanating from using okHTTP as my network layer. After days of research I found this https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-sdk/issues/321 and https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-sdk/issues/322 which outline the pifalls. on resuming to a clean Volley the maps now work as expected

Answer (score 0):

For me setting Eclipse's Preferences -> Android -> Build -> Custom keystore fixed the problem. Also uninstall app and clean build.