# Google Maps v2 - Error

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I have just followed this tutorial (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2) to present the Google Maps. However, when I try to initialize the application in my phone (ZTE V875) I get an error, or better saying a list of errors. Does anyone know why? Thanks in advance.

In my MainActivity.class I have the following code:

```
package com.example.tutorialgooglemaps;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tutorialgooglemaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

        <permission
          android:name="com.example.tutorialgooglemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
          android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

        <uses-permission android:name="com.example.tutorialgooglemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

        <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion= "0x00020000"
            android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="MYKEY"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.tutorialgooglemaps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Error output

```
01-28 18:21:59.219: I/Process(22828): Sending signal. PID: 22828 SIG: 9
01-28 18:22:23.499: E/ActivityThread(22977): >>> handling: 110
01-28 18:22:23.509: D/ActivityThread(22977): <<< done: 110
01-28 18:22:23.509: E/ActivityThread(22977): >>> handling: 100
01-28 18:22:23.519: D/AndroidRuntime(22977): Shutting down VM
01-28 18:22:23.519: W/dalvikvm(22977): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aac4560)
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tutorialgooglemaps/com.example.tutorialgooglemaps.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1745)
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1761)
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124)
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:947)
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3822)
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:209)
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    at com.example.tutorialgooglemaps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1709)
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    ... 11 more
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.tutorialgooglemaps-2.apk]
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
01-28 18:22:23.529: E/AndroidRuntime(22977):    ... 20 more
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that you can't have Fragment as root-layout.

Comment: Your code and your crash do not appear to line up. The crash acts as though you are trying to load a layout containing `<fragment>` from an activity that does not know about `<fragment>`. Your code, though, is using `FragmentActivity`, which is correct. The line numbers in the stack trace do not match your supplied code (the trace says you are calling `setContentView()` on line 11, whereas the pasted code it is not until at least line 13).

Comment: Thanks GuiceU that was the problem!! I add a <LinearLayout> that contains the <fragment> part and know the code is running perfectly.
Thank you all for the replies! :)

Comment: api v2 is deprecated now. you should upgrade to v3

Comment: Thanks for the info Rachel.
I read about the v3 (https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/android_v3) but i have one doubt, how can I create the "map" they refer in the 7 point? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone had the same problem, the problem is at the activity_main.xml where a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout is needed. Thanks to everyone

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I commented on a similar problem. Perhaps my answer can also solve your problem!?

[google map - runtimeexception - error inflating class fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386631/google-map-runtimeexception-error-inflating-class-fragment/14386980#14386980)

Comment: Thanks, but I have that correctly configured and I'm still getting the errors. I just followed this tutorial to configure the project and import all the libraries. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mRnEkP2q4fo
Thanks